# iPhone facebook connect FQL Query to get user's friends

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get a list of user's friends using fb connect for the iphone.

I've tried both of the following FQL Queries, but they don't seem to be returning anything.

which one is correct if any ?

```
NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select flid,name from friendlist where owner=%lld",[self fbSession].uid];
```

or

```
NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT flid,uid FROM friendlist_member WHERE flid IN (SELECT flid FROM friendlist WHERE owner=%lld)",[self fbSession].uid];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah.. figured it out...

```
NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name,uid FROM user WHERE uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=%lld )",[self fbSession].uid];
```

Comment: I have the list of user's friends. But i wan't to display only those friends who are online in Facebook. is this possible??